# Unexpected reified type inference

Tags: kotlin

I expected the below code to be failed to compile at the last line. because it missed some type expression for type inference.

`test.kts`:

```
import kotlin.reflect.KClass

sealed class Test {
    object A : Test()
    object B : Test()

    companion object {
        fun <T : Test> getByClass(c: KClass<T>): T =
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            when (c) {
                A::class -> A as T
                B::class -> B as T
                else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected class: $c")
            }

        inline fun <reified T : Test> get(): T = getByClass(T::class)
    }
}

fun f1(a: Test.A) {
    println(a::class)
}

fun f2(a: Any) {
    println(a::class)
}

// Works right
f1(Test.get())

// Just invocation get raises compile error
// Test.get()

// Providing type raises compile error
// Test.get<Any>()
// f2(Test.get<Any>())

// This does not throw compile error
f2(Test.get())
```

Outputs and versions in my terminal:

```
$ kotlinc -version
info: kotlinc-jvm 1.4.21 (JRE 11.0.5+10)
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil to method java.util.ResourceBundle.setParent(java.util.ResourceBundle)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
$ kotlinc -script test.kts
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil to method java.util.ResourceBundle.setParent(java.util.ResourceBundle)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
class Test$Test$A
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unexpected class: class Test$Test
        at Test$Test$Companion.getByClass(test.kts:13)
        at Test.<init>(test.kts:32)
```

This script raises `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unexpected class: class Test$Test` at 13th line in `getByClass`. The `get()` seems to get `Test` class as a reified class.

How I should write `get()` as type safe? I want the code to be failed at compile, not at runtime.

Comment: Interesting question. May I ask for the scenario? What would you like to achieve? Maybe there is a different way of doing it. Or are you just interested for an explanation how to make it fail at compile time?

Comment: umm.. actually i want the both. The trailing question was chosen after some consideration. I want to know three things. 1) Is there a better implementation of this sealed class which resolves instances by reified class? 2) How I should write `get()` as type safe? (trailing one) Because runtime error investigations are more difficult than compile error. 3) Does this inference follow the specs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an **alternative way** of getting a type from a `sealed class`. You can use the `sealedSubclasses` from `KClass`:

```kotlin
sealed class Service {
  
  object A : Service()
  object B : Service()
  object C : Service()

  companion object {
    val all: List<Service> = Service::class.sealedSubclasses
            .map { it.objectInstance as Service }

    fun findByClass(kClass: KClass<out Service>): Service = all.first { it::class == kClass }
}
```

You could then look for a concrete sub type using `findByClass()`:

```kotlin
val serviceC: ServiceC = Service.findByClass(Service.C::class)
```

**Note**
`findByClass()` can safely return a non null value, though `first` can throw an exception when the element is not present, but because of parameter `kClass: KClass<out Service>` we can only pass a sub type of `Service`. So that class type must be available.

Comment: Thanks. I had not noticed that  my `getByClass` is already not type safe.

Answer (score 0):

the reason is you are doing this in the static block of class Test, so it is passing the function the main class type, not the instance type(it's a class method not an instance method). you need to change it so that it could be only called on the instances like A and B (non-static). something like this can work:

```
sealed class Test {
    object A : Test()
    object B : Test()

    companion object {
        fun <T : Test> getByClass(c: KClass<T>): T =
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            when (c) {
                A::class -> A as T
                B::class -> B as T
                else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected class: $c")
            }
    }

    fun get(): Test {
        return getByClass(this::class)
    }
}


fun main() {
    val b = Test.B
    println(b.get())
}
```

Comment: I added an example works right. I want just wrapper static method for `getByClass` with reified generics. `f1` type inference is success because the `f1` argument is `Test.A`. I want to know how I should write `get()` to get compile error at the line calls `f2`.

Comment: I know what you are trying to do but static methods are not the way to do this. If you want to know the type of child classes, you need to call the methods on instances otherwise you always get the type of super class. What you're trying to do can't work because you need the instance to know its type

Comment: F1 is success because you force it to be. What you did is like calling the get method like this `Test.get<Test.A>()`. I say this again, you can't get the child class type  unless you have the instance. How could it be possible that without the instance you know the type?

Comment: I know "you can't get the child class type unless you have the instance." So that I want compile error in this case.